# Django MultipleObjectsReturned

Tags: django, many-to-many

Let's say that I have a blog entry with multiple tags. The tags field is a ManyToMany in my model. I want to take all blog entries and for each entry I want to get all tags.

Basically I would do something like that

```
entries = Entries.objects.get(author=user)
for entry in entries:
     tags[entry.pk] = entry.tags.all()
```

The problem is that I get the MultipleObjectsReturned error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to return all entries with `author=user`, then use [`filter()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters)

```
entries = Entries.objects.filter(author=user)
```

At the moment, you are using [`get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters), which expects to return one `Entries` object. As there is more that one `Entries` with `author=user`, you get the `Entries.MultipleObjectsReturned` error.

Note, with Django, the convention is to use the singular name `Entry` for your model, instead of the plural `Entries`.

Answer (score 4):

You're using `get`, when you should be using `filter`.

Only use `get` when there's only one possible result. In that case, you get back the object itself, *not* a queryset. There is then nothing to loop over, so the `for` is extraneous.

If you actually expect a queryset, you must use `filter`.